# Random icons disappear from desktop

Tags: 20.04, icons, desktop-environments

After upgrading to 20.04, I have experienced this occasionally, I do not know what triggers it.

A random selection of the desktops file and folder icons disappear from my desktop. They are still in the "files desktop" folder but they are not displayed on the screen. If I sign off and back on to my account then they reappear.

Comment: Are using the Desktop Icons Extension by ubuntu? or some other desktop extension?

Comment: As far as I know I am not using any extension. At least I have not added any myself. I guess I am using whatever comes with UBUNTU 20.04.

Comment: I see. Can you send a screenshot of the extensions app?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for. Do you want a screen shot of my desktop? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Have ever installed any extensions on ubuntu? If yes, Maybe I can help you, if not, I can help you give an alternative.

Comment: Follow this guide, https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/ . And then disable the "Desktop Icons" extension using the extensions app and install this one instead -> https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/ . And if you still experience issues, let me know

Comment: The pre installed desktop icons extension was not enabled.
Actually none of the three pre installed extensions was enabled!
I enabled the pre installed desktop icons extension.

I am running GNOME Shell 3.36.7 and there does not seem to be a
version of extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding for that shell.
Which version [if any] should I try to use?

Comment: Did the desktop icons still disappear after enabling the pre installed extension? If not, then there's not much need to install the desktop ng ding extension, if you're still having the issue, then go install the gnome shell extension on firefox or chromium based browser and then just toggle on the switch on the link I provided to desktop ng ding

Comment: I have not been able to understand or follow the suggestion made by @Heisenberg. I thought that the issue was resolved for a while, but it reoccurs at an infrequent interval. It has also occurred  once in a window opened by the "Files" icon at the left of the screen. So it may not be related to a desktop extension after all. I have created before and after screen shots of the error on the desktop. They can be seen in the folder at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LX4r4JmDOwbEWo0tY7ra8kFhS4l7GDtU?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you just upload the images to imgur.com? I don't have access to your drive folder and don't want to give my email to a stranger.

Comment: I do not use imgur but I have shared the folder, sorry that I forgot to do so earlier. You should be able to access the images now at  now at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LX4r4JmDOwbEWo0tY7ra8kFhS4l7GDtU?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'll be able to help you here. I thought that when you had the error, every icon disappears on the desktop (In that case I might have been able to help you), but in your case that''s not the case.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway. I just have to hope that someone else has an idea that could help.